# which option gives me better performance: a variable declaration or an implicit function in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

Not always less code is better, this is my last lesson learned

So it came to me this question

in terms of memory management, speed and all that, what's better??

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Notification" 
                                                 message:@"My message" 
                                                delegate:self 
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Cancelar",nil];
[message show];
```

or

```
[[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Notification" 
                           message:@"My message" 
                          delegate:self 
                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                 otherButtonTitles:@"Cancelar",nil]show];
```

this is a very short difference (2 lines against one) but this can be even more complex when you're reducing more code with more complex code and functions

thanks in advance for the answer

Comment: I believe both do the same thing and thus, use the same amount of memory... Even if they didn't it would save you almost NO memory by changing from one to the other. As for speed, if there is a difference (which there probably isn't), you wouldn't be able to perceive it.

Comment: If your question was answered, make sure you accept one of them. Otherwise this will look like an unfinished Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be no perceivable change in speed and, as they both perform the same action, there is also no saving on memory.

To give an analogy, What takes less thinking, reading "it's a boy!" or "it is a boy!"?

You take about the same amount of time to process the information, regardless of the spelling differentiation between the two, and that time is almost nothing.

To answer your question (or what I think is your question). There is almost no difference in memory savings between the two, and you will not save any processing time.

It is also better to make your code be easier to read. Trying to read smashed code will probably waste more time than trying to process such a minute difference, as in your example.

Comment: thank you all for your answers it's clear now the process is the same even if it takes two or three lines more

Answer (score 4):

The allocated memory on the heap is the same, i.e. the one required by the `UIAlertView` instance.

The latter would save you a variable declaration on the stack, which is definitely neglectable with respect to the context you're working in.

There won't be any noticeable speed improvement, so just stick with good coding style, make a variable and save yourself a headache when reading back your own code.

Answer (score 2):

While your second solution will take up a tiny bit less memory and time, it is usually preferred that code be readable rather than optimized.  In most cases, code is developed by a team of people, and it is better that everyone reading that code can quickly and easily understand what it is doing.  As a general rule, don't optimize unless it is proven necessary (e.g. it is noticeably slowing things down or causing it to use too much memory).

Comment: *it is usually preferred that code be readable rather than optimized* +1.  The compiler can usually optimize most of the stuff you try to do yourself anyway.